# Hyperbolic isometry and product

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $g:D^n\rightarrow D^n$ be a hyperbolic isometry, so it is a mobius transformation. Then, $g$ can be expressed as a composition $T\circ R$ where  $T$ is a translation such that $T(0)=g(0)$ and $R$ is a Euclidean isometry fixing the origin.

My attempt: Since $g$ is mobius, $g$ is either on $O(n)$ or $g=f\circ R$ where $f$ is in $O(n)$ and $R$ is a rotation about a euclidean sphere. Here $g$ sends $0$ to $0$.

What is quick way to see this?

If $T$ is a hyperbolic translation from $0$ to $g(0)$ (which exists because hyp space is homogeneous) then consider $T^{-1}g$. Here, $T^{-1}g(0)=0$ and so $T^{-1}g$ is conjugate to a rotation and rotation is euclidean isometry.

But why this conjugation preserves euclidean isometry?

Comment: Why did you write "conjugate"?

Comment: @MoisheKohan because it is elliptic

Comment: Now prove that conjugation is not needed.

Comment: Start by thinking why each elliptic is conjugate to an orthogonal transformation.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Just a question, suppose I take a point on the boundary $x\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, how do I interpret a hyperbolic isometry $g':\overline{D}^n\rightarrow \overline{D}^n$ such that $g'(x)=0$?

Comment: You prove that it does not exist.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  is there much difference in theory from hyperbolic geometry in dimension 2 and higher dimensional? I mean is there a result in dimension 2 that doesn't hold in higher dimensions? in terms of elementary hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: No, you have to go beyond "elementary" for that.

Comment: Are you willing to use the formula for a Mobius transformation?

Comment: @Deane yes I am willing

Comment: Then it’s not hard to find a formula for $T$ and show that any Mobius transformation that maps $0$ to $0$ is a rotation.